# Is there any way to make a probabilistic constant time equality check on collection types?

Tags: performance, algorithm

### The Problem

I have wondered on how to make an efficient comparison of two collection types (lists, sets, maps, etc.). It should be noted that it is structural equality that is desired not reference-based equality.

Usually one has to iterate through all the elements of the collection and running a comparison between them at a cost of O(1) per comparison yielding astonishing O(n) comparison time.

This can impact using a hash-table of lists where a collision check is fairly expensive or using contractual design (e.g. comparing and old collection with new).

### Direction of Current Solution

I have though of ways to determine fast solutions, but they all seem probalistic/non-deterministic. The ideas is if one is able to use some kind of unique hash of all the elements which can be stored and compared. A good hash algorithm should provide enough enthropy such that there is a small possibility of collision.

This hash-based comparison technique could be strengthen by using somekind of constant time comparison of list head (like comparing the first 10 elements). Two lists with the same elements at the start and using a good hash algorithm should provide in theory somewhat of unique comparison.

### The Question

Is it possible to create a kind of constant-time comparison (both generalized and specialized on some time like integers), and can it be achieved through a unique-hash technique?

### The Update

To clarify the question, I do not need a perfect equality check but a quick "pre-equality" check, as a way to speed up a real equality check afterwards. While many hash-code implementations are useful for set comparison, I am also interested in list (ordered) comparison.

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements in the collection, or just whether it contains the same objects in any order?

Comment: The equality should hold the collection property, i.e. a list should be ordered, a set should containt unique elements etc.

Comment: Do your collections often hold the same number of elements, or do they tend to hold greatly varying numbers of elements?

Comment: @EricJ. For the varying number of elements it is often easy to do a length check (for many collections if designed right). It it therefore more of a way to differentiate collections of the same number of elements I am looking for.

Comment: I'd say computing hash values for sets and **ordered** lists makes combinatorially no difference.

Comment: @DaveBall the idea was more that the comparison technique could be different, not the hash itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a couple of minutes to write such a collection class in C#, source below. I used the generic `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` because it's easy to override its functionality.

Haven't tested it at all, but it should be a solid start IMHO. Note that `UpdateHash` takes indices into account (making the hash function slightly better), while an analogue `HashedSet<T>` would skip this part.

Also, due to reversibility of the `XOR` operator, recalculating the hash on add/remove takes `O(1)` complexity. If a better hash is needed, these operations would grow to `O(n)`, so I recommend profiling and then deciding what's best.

```
public class HashedList<T> : Collection<T>, IEquatable<HashedList<T>>
{
    private int _hash;
    private void UpdateHash(int index, T item)
    {
        _hash ^= index;
        if (item != null)
            _hash ^= item.GetHashCode();
    }

    #region Overriden collection methods

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        UpdateHash(index, item);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        UpdateHash(index, this[index]);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        _hash = 0;
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        UpdateHash(index, this[index]);
        UpdateHash(index, item);
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }

    #endregion 

    #region Value equality

    public bool Equals(HashedList<T> other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        if (other.Count != this.Count)
            return false;

        if (other._hash != this._hash)
            return false;

        return CompareElements(other);
    }

    private bool CompareElements(HashedList<T> other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this[i] == null)
            {
                if (other[i] != null)
                    return false;
            }

            if (this[i].Equals(other[i]) == false)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var hashed = obj as HashedList<T>;
        if (hashed != null)
            return Equals(hashed);

        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _hash;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You could also argue that `object.Equals` should return true if any `IList<T>` implementation with same elements is passed, but since their hash codes would then differ, it would break consistency. This is the recommended implementation for `object.Equals` IIRC.

Comment: Your UpdateHash is flawed, when You store 2 equal elements, their hashcode cancels itself out. Mush better: `_hash ^= index; _hash ^= index * item.GetHashCode()` (You might want to use `unchecked` here)

Comment: @maniek: well, this is only a simple concept and I said I haven't tested it nor examined it at all. And you cannot really say that a hash is *flawed* unless it gives *different* values for same inputs. It's important that it helps discard different collections most of the time. But yes, you suggestion seems like an improvement.

Comment: @maniek:  A small problem with that, if you do a delete from the list then you pay O(n) to recalculate the hash code.  Though I generally agree with your assessment that this is a pretty naive proposal for a hash code.

Comment: @Mikola No, You do not need to recalculate, it just works (well, except for the index=0 case, but it's easily fixable)

Comment: I have accepted this answer on the base of using C# code which could provide useful for future references looking for a similar answer.

Comment: As a note you should probably do this in your non-generic equals function instead of returning base.Equals always (and ignoreng compareelements result), `if (hashed != null) { return (this as IEquatable<HashList<T>>).Equals(hashed); } else { return false; }`

Comment: @YetAnother: yes, of course, that was a mistake, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Use hash based comparison.

Hash( SetA ) vs Hash (SetB ).

PS: You need to sort (or any other deterministic ordering) the elements in the sets before calculating hash. It is possible that hashes may match, but not the collections (due to hash collision), but chances of that happening are pretty low.

PS:PS: I am assuming that the collections are static (or, almost static). In that case you can pre-compute hashes during the creation of the collection itself. So it is O(1) for each comparison. Otherwise, as Groo mentioned, use XOR based hashing which is pretty efficient.

Follow up: Using information theory it is possible to prove that if X and Y each can take 2^n unique values, you need to make at least O(n) comparisons. There is no getting around that. What hashing gives you is the ability to efficiently compare.

Comment: If `xor` is used for hashing, then it should work without sorting (and removing elements should also behave as expected).

Comment: If you go that route, your hashing algorithm is important.  The OP specifically does NOT want to check reference equality, but "structural" (I guess that means value) equality.  If the hash algorithm is based on the object address, this method will fail.  The hash would have to be based on the values contained in the objects.

Comment: I don't see how a hashing solution could possibly be faster than O(n).  Any useful hash function for containers would have to depend on every element on the container.  I'm also not sure why the o.p. thinks O(n) is "astonishing"ly slow for comparing containers.

Comment: @japreiss: checking for equality should be O(1) on average. Creating the hash is always more expensive than simply comparing elements (unless you choose a const hash), but you only need to do it once for a collection, and once done you can discard unequal collection quickly. For many comparisons, it will make a difference.

Comment: If you could precompute/cache the hash value of the set and update it for every insertion and removal in O(1), a comparison would also be O(1)...

Comment: @DaveBall: The idea is to move the cost of element hash generation and updating the collection hash to the Insert methods, so that set comparison is fast.

Comment: @DaveBall: that's what XOR is good for. It's far from being a perfect hash function, but it adds negligible computation overhead and it can be accumulated as elements are added. On element removal, XORing the hash with that element's hash value also restores the hash to its previous value.

Answer (score 1):

One could use [**bloom filters**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) for this task [for sets]. Each set will also have a bloom filter attached to it.

If the two filters are identical - the structures are **probably identical**.

If the two filters are not identical - the stuructures are **definetly different** from each other.

**The up side:**

No false negatives. If the filters are different - the structures are different.

**The down side:**

You might have false positives. You will need to have an extra check [full traversal] to make sure that 2 structures are indeed identical.

Note that false positive rate is a function of the bloom filter's size - the bigger it is - the less False Positives you get.

Also note: since bloom filters are actually bitsets - comparing two bloom filters can be implemented very efficiently.

Comment: I think bloom filters are a great suggestion (+1) if no elements are removed from the collection. If the use of many hash functions is too expensive, you can give up independence of the hash functions and gain much faster computations (see e.g. http://spinroot.com/spin/Workshops/ws04/040-spin2004.pdf).

Comment: @DaveBall: I actually don't think bloom filters have anything to do with OP's question. OP does not want to check if an element is a part of a set, but instead wants to compare two sets (each set being a "single element" in his/her case, for all it's worth). Creating a bloom filter for a set, only to compare it to a different bloom filter, is no different from creating a single hash value (of arbitrary size) for comparison.

Comment: @Groo: Doesn't your last sentence show that bloom filters do have to do something with OP's question? Isn't the complete bloom filter a very good hash value for the set? The downside I see is it's computationally expensive, for which my previous comment is a solution.

Comment: @DaveBall: yes, bloom filters will work, but no, they are not a good hash value for the set. If you need to check if an element belongs to a set, they are perfect, but they are simply not created for this purpose. Calculating the filter with *k* hash functions takes `O(k*n)` every time an element is added/removed, and there is no justification to do this when only a single general purpose function (like murmurhash) yields same results in terms of collisions. Increasing or decreasing *k* also has no direct influence on the quality of the bit-array when used as a plain hash value.

Comment: Let a \in S, b \not\in S, such that murmur(a) == murmur(b). Then murmur(S with b instead of a) == murmur(S), right? If you use multiple hash functions, you avoid this likely collision at the expense of creating a different collision, but which is probably more unlikely (e.g. with a set with different size). As I have cited before, you do not need pure bloom filters, using multiple hash functions which are not independent does almost as good a job, and is almost as fast as a single hash function.

Comment: @DaveBall: you are talking about two completely different things. A hash function like murmurhash will cause each element of the set to change a large number of bits in the final hash value. On the other hand, each successive hash function used in a bloom filter only contributes a **single bit** in the final hash value, which is then OR-ed with existing bits. That's actually very little information, and is the reason why bloom filters require large bit-arrays (more than 9 bits per element for 1% false positive rate). In this context, that is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very useful (and detailed) discussion on the topic including reference implementations for several collection types.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2986.pdf

> In general, computing permutations is a quadratic operation.  However,
>   given two unordered  containers that use the same hash and
>   key-equivalence functions, the elements will be partitioned into 
>   key-equivalence groups that make comparison much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a secure hash function the chance of a collision is vanishingly small (and if you use an up-to-date hash function you get to write a paper if you find a collision :-)).

If your collection is implemented as a tree then you could maintain a hash computed from the leaves up to the root at cost a constant factor times the cost of the tree update you have to do anyway. Unfortunately, the constant factor in computing a secure hash is probably pretty big. Double-unfortunately, you need two collections with the same objects to have the same tree structure. This works with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree, but not with typical balanced trees, where the history or updates affects the tree structure.

Perfect hash functions are usually tuned to be perfect for a particular collection, which probably won't work in your case. If a hash function maps to the numbers 1..N, then given N+1 objects, there will always be at least one collision.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is **theoretically impossible**: If you have hash values of 32 bit, you can only differentiate 2^32 variants, but lists can grow arbitrarily large. With the same argument, in runtime <= k cycles, you can only do roughly k comparisons.

If you do not want 100% guarantee, you can use a hash function, of course. I wouldn't reinvent the wheel, though, which usually leads to worse results then using **standard libraries**. For instance, you might forget to:

- let the length of the list strongly influence the hash function.
- override equals(), too
- respect all contracts for equals() and hashCode() (cf. Josh Bloch's Effective Java or http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html, http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html).

Comment: Of course it is theoretically impossible to do it for all types of collections for all types of length. All I need is a probalistically strong way of doing it, such that collection inequality can be checked faster.

Comment: I believe by "constant time" OP meant "constant time on average". As with any hashing solution, it is obvious that there will be collisions, but it's important that a different hash value **always** means that collections are different. If many comparisons are going to be made, it is reasonable to try to reduce the search space. And, depending on the hash function, 32 bits is actually quite a large number in terms of today usual RAM sizes.

Comment: If one is comparing a relatively small number of collections with a large enough hash (I am partial to 64-bit City Hash), the chances of two collections of equal length (!) also having the same hash are vanishingly small.  It's probably more likely that the computer will be hit by a meteor than you'll fall victim to the Birthday Problem with a 64+ bit hash and a reasonably small number of collections.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading with "but lists can grow arbitrarily large" because you can respond by making your hash size grow arbitrarily large. @EricJ.: You CAN run into the birthday paradox: it only takes a billion elements to run into the birthday paradox with 64bits; a billion 64-bit elements can reasonably fit in modern RAM. However if you just move to 128bit hashes, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
hash(structure) := hast(item1) ^ hash(item2) ^ ... ^ hash(item_n)
```

Depending on the hash function (and first of all, on its output size) this will give you a good false positive probability. It does not yield false negatives, and is easily implemented with insertion and removal in short constant time. They beat bloom filters in that the false positive probability does not depend on the number of elements.

For arrays or lists - how probable are arrays with the same contents in different order? If they are, you could easily make the hash dependant on the item position:

```
hash(structure) := hast(item1, 1) ^ hash(item2, 2) ^ ... ^ hash(item_n, n)
```

In that case, removal and insertion can be O(1) at the end of the array. Random insertions in the middle are more difficult, but then again, they are O(n) for arrays anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought upon reading your question is what you mean by "probabilistic".  Are you thinking of probabilistic methods as a way to get some kind of precise (countable) answer that is correct (no error)?  Or are you willing to incur some amount of error in the result?

In the latter case, you can take advantage of asymptotic "equivalence" when comparing data after applying a log function.  Consider [Linear Counting](http://dblab.kaist.ac.kr/Publication/pdf/ACM90_TODS_v15n2.pdf):

- Create a zero-initialized bit-map **b** of size **m**
- Choose a hash function **f**
- Apply f to each input, obtaining value **v**
- Set the bit-map at position **v** to 1

To compute the count, the formula is:

**n** = -**m** * ln(**Un** / **m**)

Where:

- **n**  -> the approximate count
- **Un** -> Number of zero bits in m

For appropriately sizing **m**, see the link above to the original paper.  Also, see this recent blog post which also includes HyperLogLog:

http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/4/5/big-data-counting-how-to-count-a-billion-distinct-objects-us.html

Comment: Fascinating read, thank you. The linked blog post however failed to mention what they were really trying to do though: calculate the total number of unique elements, not the total number of elements; this made the read a bit confusing for the first five minutes. Hopefully this clarifies things for other readers.